# unbind a prettyPhoto element

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I have a question about Jquery, it is possible to unbind an element to a script. Example:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
```

I want to run something like:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").unbind('prettyPhoto');
```

and if I click on the element, the prettyPhoto doesn't work.

I have try this but... it is not working.. :/

it is possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have find the issues.

So, in the PrettyPhoto ( or others plugins ) they have some Bind event. So,

for my issue, the binding is

```
click.prettyphoto
```

so the code fixed code is:

```
 $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").unbind('click.prettyphoto');
```

:-)

I hope this will help someone!